# How to work around the require(“../../../../../../../”) frustration In NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, import, ecmascript-6

Any better ways of solving this kind of problem in node.js below?

```
import foo from "../../../modules/home/models/index.js"
import bar from "../../../modules/about/models/index.js"
import baz from "../../../modules/contact/models/index.js"
```

At least making them into something like this?

```
import foo from "/home/models/index.js"
import bar from "/about/models/index.js"
import baz from "/contact/models/index.js"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My first question would be, why are you structuring your files such that you have to do this? My recommendation would be reorganize your files, but you haven't given much to go on. Why do you need to access all the models from one file in this case?

Comment: setup your directory-tree and put your files in an other way, with less subdirectories / nearer to the code that uses it ?

Comment: In my experience, setting up a workaround for this always ends up being more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: This [article](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) surveys the methods used to alias an annoying path.

Comment: Fix your directory structure and maybe your module dependency graph.  This should not be necessary with a proper design so you should be asking how you fix the design, not how you deal with the import path.  And, we would need to know a lot more about what you're doing to suggest a better layout/architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need inversion of control.

> ./modules/home/index.js

```
 const homeModel1 = () => {
     //...
 }
 const homeModel2 = () => {
     //...
 }

 module.exports = Object.assign({}, { homeModel1, homeModel2 })
```

1. An object will be exported of the following shape:

```
 {
     homeModel1: () => {},
     homeModel2: () => {}
 }
```

2. When you add a new model, simply add it or import it into this file and then add it to the export object.

> ./modules/index.js

```
 import { homeModels } from './modules/home'
 import { aboutModels } from './modules/about'
 import { contactModels } from './modules/contact'

 module.exports = Object.assign({}, { homeModels, aboutModels, contactModels })
```

1. The models are destructured out and then exported as methods on a new object.
2. Likewise, same shape object is exported with all your models cultivated together, bringing all their dependencies with them.

> somewhere else

```
 import modules from './modules'

 const query = modules.homeModels.homeModel1()
```

*Bonus:*
To clarify, `Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)` creates a new object with the prototype set to the Object prototype, and merges the properties and methods of obj1 and obj2. In this simple form, it is essentially the same as `const obj = {}`.

A bit more advanced, is `Object.assign({}, { obj1, obj2 })` which makes obj1 and obj2 properties on the new object. You can do some simple testing to get a feel for the data structures.

We also used some destructuring. If you are having issues getting things lined up properly, you should look at those aspects plus how you are importing them into a file. For example, `import obj1 from './modules'` will bring the entire object in from ./modules, but `import { obj1 } from './modules'` will destructure obj1 from the object that it pulls in, so obj1 was a method/property of the object.

Do some research into inversion of control and dependency injection.

Comment: thanks for this idea. but can I do this `export { homeModel1, homeModel2 }` instead of `module.exports = Object.assign({}, { homeModel1, homeModel2 })`? It looks shorter and better...

Comment: Yes. The only thing you cannot do is Object.assign(Object.create(obj3), { obj1, obj2 }) which inherits the prototype-inherited methods/props from a third object (faster theoretical memory performance vs. not Object.create()). Go with export. It matches your import syntax choice.

Comment: tbh, export is probably identical once it goes through babel.